# Receive Rule Conditions Email Using Applescript

Tags: email, applescript, conditional-statements, rules

I use an applescript to store parts of incoming mails in a database. This script is called via special mail rules.
It works perfectly since months with one exception:
If the selection in the INBOX contains additionally mails which doesn't fit the criteria of the mail rule, these mails are also passed to the script (which in my eyes is a bug from Apple High Sierra) 
Therefore, I have to compare the transferred data records with the associated rule myself. Below the test script

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages theSelectedMessages for rule theRule
            tell application "Mail"
                ...

                set ruleName to name of theRule
                set ruleScriptName to name of me

                repeat with theCondition in rule conditions of theRule

                    set {expression:ruleExpr, header:ruleHeader, rule type:ruleType, qualifier:ruleQualifier} to theCondition
                    log ...
                end repeat
            end tell
        end perform mail action with messages
    end using terms from
```

The associated code from Apple in the Users SyncedRules.plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>CriterionUniqueId</key>
    <string>XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
    <key>Expression</key>
    <string>noreply@email.com</string>
    <key>Header</key>
    <string>From</string>
    <key>Qualifier</key>
    <string>EndsWith</string>
</dict>
```

Problem: I always receive following data values for the rule conditions:

```
ruleExpr: noreply@email.com
ruleType: 束constant ****tfro損
ruleHeader:
ruleQualifier: 束constant ****rqbw損
```

The variable "ruleHeader" should actually contain the value "from" but is empty.
In addition, the contents of "ruleType" and "ruleQualifier" are also not readable.

The "function library" of the Script editor doesn't help.

There are a lot of hints in the internet to add a new Rule but I didn't find any docs nor tipps to receive the content of a rule condition.
Any help is appreciated !

Comment: You may need to coerce the enumerations to a string, if that is what you are using elsewhere (comparisons, etc).  The ruleQualifier `rqbw` is `begins with value` and ruleType `tfro` is `from header` - you can see what the raw enumerators are by viewing the Mail scripting definitions (.sdef) in the application bundle.

Comment: I found 
http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/Hacked%20Team.git/core-macos/core/RCSNativeMail.h and 
https://github.com/tingraldi/SwiftScripting/blob/master/Frameworks/MailScripting/MailScripting/Mail.sdef
Any idear to use these elements to check the incoming message ?

Comment: You would probably run into the same issue.  The Script Editor tries to help you out by expanding constants and enumerators returned by an application, but you don't get that when running a compiled script outside the Script Editor.  If you want to use the _name_ of those constants, you will need to create you own lookup table or otherwise load the scripting terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for the part "ruleHeader" of my question:

```
            ...
                #set {expression:ruleExpr, header:ruleHeader, rule type:ruleType, qualifier:ruleQualifier} to theCondition

                tell theCondition
                    set ruleExpr to the expression
                    set ruleHeader to the header key
                    set ruleType to the rule type
                    set ruleQualifier to the qualifier
                end tell
            ...
```

The result of the return parameters are now correct:

```
Type: 束constant ****tfro損
Header: 束constant erutthdk損
Qualifier: 束constant ****rqew損
```

To separate the values (type constants) I use

```
set commandType to rich text 15 thru 18 of (ruleType as string)
set commandHeader to rich text 11 thru 18 of (ruleHeader as string) 
set commandQualifier to rich text 15 thru 18 of (ruleQualifier as string)
```

and get

```
commandType: tfro
commandHeader: erutthdk
commandQualifier: rqew
```

You can find the explanation of these constants here: http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/Hacked%20Team.git/core-macos/core/RCSNativeMail.h

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using the enumerator (e.g. `rqew`) rather than its name (e.g. `ends with value`)?  Note that the rule header is not a message header.

Comment: How to get the name´s (command´s) instead of then enum´s of the conditions of the currently running rule ?

Comment: I've posted an answer with an example.

Comment: on every (3) options the result was: 
"Attempted comparison:
"mike.bestian@example.com" missing value "noreply"
The result:
Error:  the operation 'does contain value' was not found.
--> the problem is the word "value" in the variable ruleQualifier which is not part of a command

Comment: and because of that, the row "if lookup is not missing value then" is always false

Comment: You will get that when running from the Script Editor or loading the terminology using `ascrgdut`, since that is the name of the constant.  If you use the raw constant that is returned to an app, it is used to look up the correct term for the `run script` statement, otherwise additional code will be needed to strip out undesired words from the name.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to get the value of an application constant.  One is to get the constants and values from the scripting dictionary and provide a way to look them up, and another is to use a secret (well, not that secret) command to load user terminology.

The following example displays the constants using different methods - I kept them separate so you could see if there is any delay when loading terms.  Save it as an application, since the Script Editor already loads the application terminology and normally doesn't use the raw constants:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

tell application "Mail"
    set ruleQualifier to qualifier of some rule condition of rule "News from Apple" -- example rule
    set ruleExpr to (get sender of some message of some mailbox) -- example sender from random message
    set match to "noreply" -- example text to compare

    set method to button returned of (display dialog "Choose method to look up terminology" buttons {"Load via 'ascrgdut'", "Expand Constant", "Raw constant"} default button 3)
    if method is "Expand Constant" then -- manually look up constant name
        display dialog "The supplied term:" & return & my expandQualifier(ruleQualifier) with title method buttons {"OK"}
    else
        if method is "Load via 'ascrgdut'" then -- load terminology to get the name of the enumerator
            try
                «event ascrgdut» -- may be a slight delay while loading
            end try
        end if
        display dialog "The supplied term:" & return & ruleQualifier as string with title method buttons {"OK"}
    end if
end tell

# You can also use something like 'run script' to perform operations based on the qualifier:
tell me to activate
set comparison to quote & ruleExpr & quote & space & expandQualifier(ruleQualifier) & space & quote & match & quote
display dialog "Attempted comparison:" & return & comparison & return & return & "The result:" & return & (my performComparison(ruleExpr, ruleQualifier, match)) with title "Comparison Result" buttons {"OK"}


on expandQualifier(theItem) -- look up comparison name/operator from constant - returns 'missing value' if not found
    set ruleQualifiers to {rqbw:"begins with", rqco:"contains", rqdn:"does not contain", rqew:"ends with", rqie:"equal to", rqlt:"less than", rqgt:"greater than"}
    set dict to current application's NSDictionary's dictionaryWithDictionary:ruleQualifiers

    set theItem to theItem as text
    if theItem ends with "»" then -- look up constant from raw chevron syntax
        set lookup to dict's objectForKey:(text -5 thru -2 of theItem)
    else
        set lookup to dict's objectForKey:theItem
    end if
    if lookup is not missing value then set lookup to lookup as text
    return lookup
end expandQualifier

to performComparison(theItem, operation, theValue)
    set lookup to expandQualifier(operation)
    if lookup is not missing value then
        try
            return (run script quote & theItem & quote & space & (lookup as text) & space & quote & theValue & quote)
        on error errmess number errnum
            return "Error:  " & errmess
        end try
    else
        return "Error:  the operation " & quoted form of (operation as text) & " was not found."
    end if
end performComparison
```

Note that the handlers use the raw constants that an application would be getting.  If loading the terminology you will need to adjust the lookup record/dictionary to the terms you are using.

Comment: Wow, work perfect ! Didn´t find any docs about the "«event ascrgdut» " ? Is it possible to use the result (e.g. "begins with") as a command to compare two variables ? May be with a reference to a handler ?

Comment: There isn't any official documentation, but it has been around for a while - this [MacScripter](https://www.macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=39242) topic, for example.  You could possibly use `run script` to perform your own operations - I've edited my answer to include a comparison handler.

Comment: Handler doesn´t work: parameter "operation": row set operation to operation as text -->script error --> couldn´t convert into text (same with string).

Comment: Updated - some quoting got missed for the `run script` statement.

Comment: the problem seems to be earlier: after "set ruleQualifier to (qualifier of contents of theCondition)" the var ruleQualifier contain "begins with value", so the list assignment "set ruleOperations to {rqbw:"begins with", rqco"...." doesn´t work.

Comment: Running a script in the Script Editor or using `ascrgdut` will get the name/value from the scripting definition file (e.g. `does contain value`), while an application will return a constant that can be used to look up something to use in a statement (e.g. `contains`).  I think we are using different methods - if you are using `ascrgdut `, try using the constant instead (or describe _exactly_ what you are doing).

Comment: I copied your first example code and the "Edit" (performComparison ...) code into a new script and tried it out.
The only change: "display dialog my expandQualifier (ruleQualifier) with title" Expand Constant "buttons {" OK "}) has been changed to "set myResult to my performComparison (ruleExpr, theCondition, "noreply") ". "ruleExpr" contains "@mail.com"
I immediately get the error: «class rucr» 2 of «class rule» "my rule to test" of Application Mail could not convert to type of text (row "set operation to operation as text").

Comment: Looks like you are passing the entire rule condition (`rule condition 2 of rule "my rule to test"`) instead of one of the qualifier constants (`rqxx`).  I've edited my answer to a self-contained example, using a condition from Mail's original "News from Apple" rule (which just has a bunch of "From contains whatever" conditions), a random message, and a match string (change as desired).  The script needs to be saved as an application to get the constants.